# Not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I'm trying to use kubectl to work on a EKS Cluster created from an other user.
I followed the different instructions from [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-kubeconfig.html) to create the kube config file with the command : `aws eks --region eu-central-1 update-kubeconfig --name internal --role-arn arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:role/eks_role_internal`.

Then when i try to test the configuration (`kubectl get svc`), i'm getting the error :

```
could not get token: AccessDenied: User: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:user/me is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/eks_role_internal
```

Here is the config for the Policy :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxx:role/eks_role_internal"
        }
    ]
}
```

And the trust relationship of the role :

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "eks.amazonaws.com",
          "ec2.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Is your policy attached which role?

Comment: In the "Policy Usage" tab of my policy, I have my user and the role (eks_role_internal)

Comment: The error message indicates that your user is not authorized to assume role. Can you update the trust relationship of the IAM role to include the user as well and try?

Answer (score 1):

The first reason getting this error message is misconfigured `Trusted relationship` on a role that is going to be assumed.

I also was seeing this error when the attached condition in the trusted relationship of having MFA wasn't met:

```
"Condition": {"Bool": {"aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": true}}
```

AWS `cli` isn't smart enough to see this case and ask for the MFA code, it just throws that error message.

Comment: This was exactly the problem I was having. Thank you